# Wordpress content - border not expanding to full width

Tags: html, wordpress, xhtml, css

Okay this page

http://www.cg-hq.com/?s=test

you will see my test board that the border line is not all the way down. I adjusted for height certain size but if content is not that long it does not go down all the way

http://www.cg-hq.com/

Here you will see it is fine as i added width 600px. But if you go to first link it is broken cause it is longer.

Please help me as i am going crazy. I tried to set height to 100 percent and also set min height. I put it back to original for someone to help.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what precisely is broken on the first link. Could you describe it more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page that is correct only has a div#r_sidebar on the right.  The test page has both the div#l_sidebar and div#r_sidebar stacked below.  You'll need to sync up some of the #l_sidebar styles to match #r_sidebar if you want these to stack and look like one div.

In your styles.css file on line 257 add this:

```
#l_sidebar {
border-left: 1px solid #E2DDDE;
border-right: 1px solid #E2DDDE;
float: right;
font: 11px/18px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 19px 20px;
width: 294px;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow i could not believe how dumb i was . I forgot to take that one out. Homepage i do not have that one at all and Search.php i left it in. That is why it was off. Thanks so much. I knew it was something silly.